# Probable permissions issue with Windows 8.1 Pro(64) Start/Tiles

Tags: windows-8.1, permissions, windows-explorer, tiles

Due to lack of space on my current installation (30GB SSD as main disk), I have been moving a few of the "System" items to a secondary HD. The latest of these changes was to move the users[myUser]\AppData\Local directory by using the "Properties->Location" tab. However, when I did this, the system ran into some kind of permissions issue and after a few attempts I cancelled.

When I restarted the OS, the Desktop appears blank and the Start button does nothing. Since I have Process Explorer installed as well I am able to restart the Explorer with elevated permissions and the desktop appears as it should, but when I try to start any of the Tile-Programs, they complain about running the File Explorer with elevated permissions.

This makes me believe that I have some permissions problem (the Explorer at first runs with some set of permissions and when restarted with another) but I have been unable to assign the proper permissions to the User's folders.

Has anyone else seen these problems before? Does anyone know what "user" or what kind of "permissions" Explorer has on startup?

Comment: You basically performed, an unsupported action.  My best advice for a solution, create a new user, and only move specific folders within that directory.  There is a duplicate of this question that explains more on the rason this happened.

Comment: @Ramhound, could you please elaborate? I thought the "Location" tab of the Properties was a "safe" way to perform the change. Also: could you point me to the duplicate of this question? Thanks.

Comment: I believe the permissions problems were because you attempted to move the folder which stores the Windows Store application data.  Why this woudl have affected the desktop, I suspect, you tried to move the entire user profile by mistake while you were logged in.

Comment: @Ramhound that makes sense. Do you happen to know which user the Explorer is using on startup? I am going to try to assign permissions to "Everyone" to the new Local folder (and its children) and see if it works. Final question: do you happen to have the link to the duplicate of this question? Thanks!

Comment: I don't have a link to the duplicate.  I can't believe nobody asked a question on how to move the folders within AppData which is the located where Modern UI applications are stored, and I do know, they specifically have really bad behavior when the physical drive is redirected/changed.